# Is the function $f(z)=e^{i\bar z^2}$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is the function $f(z)=e^{i\bar {z}^2}$ analytic?

My attempt: Let $z=x+iy$. Then $$f(z)=f(x+iy)=e^{i(x-iy)^2}=e^{2xy}\cdot e^{i(x^2-y^2)}=e^{2xy}[\cos(x^2-y^2)+i\sin(x^2-y^2)].$$ Therefore, $u(x,y)=e^{2xy}\cos(x^2-y^2)$ and $v(x,y)=e^{2xy}\sin(x^2-y^2)$. Now we want to calculate the values of $x$ and $y$ such that $u_x(x,y)=v_y(x,y)$ and $u_y(x,y)=-v_x(x,y)$. I found that those values of $x$ and $y$ have to satisfy these equations:
\begin{gather*}
x\sin(x^2-y^2)=y\cos(x^2-y^2)\\
x\cos(x^2-y^2)=-y\sin(x^2-y^2)
\end{gather*}
Clearly $(x,y)=(0,0)$ satisfies both equations, but I don't know if it is the only point of $\mathbb{C}$ that satisfies both equations.

Comment: You could try other points! It's not difficult to see that, for example, $(1, 0)$ fails to satisfy these equations, and all you need to know is that $\sin(1) \neq 0$ or $\cos(1) \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, also I had tried with the points $(x,y)$ where $x=y$, and those points also fails, but there are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: That's all you need to show that the function is not analytic everywhere. If you want to show it's analytic nowhere, you'd have to do a bit more, but as far as I'm concerned, you've answered the question.

Comment: I wanted to show that the function is analytic nowhere, but it seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's solve these equations. First, note that, if $\cos(x^2 - y^2) = 0$, then $\sin(x^2 - y^2) = \pm 1$. This means the equations simplify to $\pm x = 0$ and $\mp y = 0$, and in any case, $x = y = 0$. This contradicts $\cos(x^2 - y^2) = 0$.

By rearranging the equations, we get
\begin{align*}
x \tan(x^2 - y^2) &= y \\
y \tan(x^2 - y^2) &= -x.
\end{align*}
Multiplying them respectively by a factor of $y$ and $x$, we get
$$y^2 = yx\tan(x^2 - y^2) = xy\tan(x^2 - y^2) = -x^2,$$
and hence $x^2 + y^2 = 0$. Since $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, this implies $x = y = 0$. That is, the one and only solution is $x = y = 0$, proving that $f$ is analytic nowhere.